# Can I record directly to a computer with the HC-V250?

Tags: camera, digital-recording

I'm considering purchase of the [Panasonic HC-V250](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1023345-REG/panasonic_hc_v250_full_hd_camcorder.html), but my primary use case is recording directly to a folder on my computer. (I do a lot of post-production editing, so I need all the files on my computer.) The HC-V250 can stream via UStream, but I don't know if this means that it's also capable of recording to a computer. (I'd assume not.)

For reference, I'm using a Windows 8.1 computer. This detail also does not appear to be stated in the manual or any reviews on various sites I've found this product on.

Is it possible to use the HC-V250 to record directly to a computer, or do I have to record to the memory card and then (painfully) transfer the files?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same camera. As far as I can remember it can be used in "web cam" mode where it records straight to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to transfer via Bluetooth from the camera's SD card to a computer folder, but sorry don't remember how I did it just know we did it using Bluetooth.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a definitive answer, but I can offer a suggestion. If the camera can generate a stream, try a stream recorder. In fact, doesn't UStream offer a stream recorder of its own?

If not, google "record video stream" for several offering, some free. I use [AVC Ultimate](http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_ultimate/) (not free) but I don't know if it will capture UStream output. They have a trial version but it may not cover the stream capture feature.

Comment: Is there no quality loss when recording a stream?

Comment: No, the stream is recorded as is. What you get depends on the quality of the stream, not the recording of it. It shouldn't be hard to try it, see what you get and what parameters you can set.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot. I ordered the camera this morning, so if it comes to that I'll let you know how it goes.